# Unpredictable behavior with SetEvent and WaitForMultipleObjects

Tags: c, winapi, synchronization

I am attempting to use `SetEvent` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` so I wrote a couple of functions that I wanted to synchronize using Events. I want the first function to execute, and then signal the second function to execute, which in turn signals the first function to execute again etc.

Two events were created, one initialized to a signaled state, the other unsignaled. The only way I can get the execution to flow as expected is when putting the each thread to sleep for 10 ms. I read about some caveats about using SetEvent:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/100818-setevent-resetevent-3.html

My question is must I put my threads to sleep because these function calls require extra time to actually signal the events? When debugging sometimes an event that is set still remains unsignalled. I verify this using process explorer. My code basically looks like this:

in the main:

```
//1. FinCalcpidUpdatestruct <<  initialize to unsignalled
//2. FinUpdatestructCalcpid << initialize to signalled
FinCalcpidUpdatestruct = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("FinCalcpidUpdatestruct"));
FinUpdatestructCalcpid = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, TRUE, TEXT ("FinUpdatestructCalcpid"));


void function1()
{
    int n;
    int noGoCode;
    n=0;

    noGoCode = 0;
    while(1)
    {
    //Sleep(10);
    noGoCode = WaitForSingleObject (FinCalcpidUpdatestruct, INFINITE);
    if (noGoCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {

    //wait for FinCalcpidUpdatestruct to be signalled
    BufferOut[n] = pid_data_array -> output;

    //signal FinUpdatestructCalcpid 
    if(!SetEvent (FinUpdatestructCalcpid))
        printf("Couldn't set the event FinUpdatestructCalcpid\n");
    else{
        printf("FinUpdatestructCalcpid event set\n");
        Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("error\n");
    }
}

void function2()
{
    int nGoCode = 0;
    while(1)
    {
    //wait for FinUpdatestructCalcpid to be signalled

    // Sleep(10);
    nGoCode = WaitForSingleObject (FinUpdatestructCalcpid, INFINITE);
    if (nGoCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    if(!SetEvent (FinCalcpidUpdatestruct))
        printf("Couldn't set the event FinCalcpidUpdatestruct\n");
    else{
        printf("FinCalcpidUpdatestruct event set\n");
        Sleep(10);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("error\n");
    }//end while(1)
```

If the sleep is not used then sometimes the same function will run through the while loop a couple of times instead of ping ponging back and forth between the two functions. Any ideas?

Comment: Buffered IO in lieu of thread context switching is a cruel an heartless bitch. From your code, are you saying SetEvent *fails* ?

Comment: Well, stdout should be line-buffered if it goes to terminal. @matrixelk, is there any redirection? Also, it would be nice to see real code (which compiles): something important might have been lost here.

Comment: There might be timing issues to do with auto-reset events - have you tried making your events manual reset and calling `ResetEvent` yourself?

Comment: there is not reason to use manual events for this. A single `SetEvent()` on an auto-reset event will *never* wake more than a single waiter, even if the wait begins *after* the set. This is pretty core to how sync-events work in Windows, and we'd all be in a world of hurt if it didn't. The OPs problem is sending the `printf()` *after* the `SetEvent()`. A context switch between the two can send the second thread to-and-through the same point in the code, thereby having successive prints from the same thread. Simply messaging *before* the `SetEvent() should solve his problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem by adding a `printf` above the `SetEvent` call on each function.

The problem is that you are setting the event and then performing some output.

In `function2` the `printf` occurs after the `SetEvent`:

```
// Add a printf call here to see sensible output.
if(!SetEvent (FinUpdatestructCalcpid))
    printf("Couldn't set the event FinUpdatestructCalcpid\n");
else{
    // Thread is pre-empted by kernel here.  This is not executed immediately
    printf("FinUpdatestructCalcpid event set\n");
}
```

The kernel [preempts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) the thread running `function2` so the `FinUpdatestructCalcpid` event has now been set, without the corresponding `printf` that you're expecting.

The thread running `function1` is then executed and sets the `FinUpdatestructCalcpid` event.  The thread running `function2` is now allowed to execute and continues from where it left off.  It runs the `printf` and because the `FinUpdatestructCalcpid` event has been set it immediately runs again.

The `Sleep()` calls you're using help to make this race condition unlikely, but do not eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me cut your code short for brevity first:

```
FinCalcpidUpdatestruct = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("FinCalcpidUpdatestruct"));
FinUpdatestructCalcpid = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, TRUE, TEXT ("FinUpdatestructCalcpid"));

void function1()
{
    while(1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject (FinCalcpidUpdatestruct, INFINITE);
        // Do Something
        SetEvent (FinUpdatestructCalcpid);
        printf(...);
        Sleep(10);
    }
}

void function2()
{
    while(1)
    {
        nGoCode = WaitForSingleObject (FinUpdatestructCalcpid, INFINITE);
        SetEvent (FinCalcpidUpdatestruct);
        printf(...); // **A**
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

At basically any point of execution the control might be taken away from thread and given to another. Now suppose that `function2` already set the event and is about to print output around `**A**` in code. Before the output is printed, the control is taken away and given to `function1`. The last printed output is already from `function1` and its wait event is set, so it falls through and prints its stuff again.

When this happens, your output is once in a while:

```
function1
function2
function1
function2
function1
// When the situation **A** above happens:
function1
function2
function2
function1
// And we move on as usual further
function2
function1
function2
```

Set your events when you are done, that is after `printf`, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think...

You don't output any status until you have already set the event.  At that point, execution could switch to the other thread before you output anything.  If that thread runs first, then it might look as if one thread's loop has run through a second time -- a ping with out a pong...

But if you were to increment a global counter in between receiving a signal and setting an event, then save that counter's value to a local variable, you would probably find that one thread's count is always odd and the other's is always even (which is the behaviour you want), even if the output is not quite in order.

Comment: In win32 terms they're lock stepped enough to not have this problem.

Comment: * as per the code posted, which doesn't even compile. Anton's comment to the OP is still very valid.